# How can I filter rows out if their start date is within 90 days from today and place them out until the 1st of the following month in R?

Tags: python, r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am having difficulty finding the words to describe what I am searching for but will try. I would like to solve the following using R or Python (but preferably R).

I have a dataframe of employees with their employee ID, department, start date etc. I am looking to perform calculations for each employee but would like to ignore employees that have a start date within 90 days from today. Additionally I would like for this employee to be left out of consideration until the 1st of the following month. **So basically exclude employees until the 1st of the month following their 90th day after hire**. I do not need to include only workdays for this project.

In the below example for a report ran on May 3, 2022 I would exclude ID (22222, 33333, 44444, 666666 88888, and 99999).

```
ID    |  Dept       |  Start Date |
11111 |  Sales      |  04/10/2015 |
22222 |  Field Tech |  04/30/2022 |
33333 |  Lab tech   |  02/10/2022 | 
44444 |  Sales      |  02/01/2022 |
55555 |  Proj. Man  |  01/01/2022 |
66666 |  Administr  |  05/05/1999 |
77777 |  Field Tech |  06/25/2015 |
88888 |  Administr  |  03/01/2022 |
99999 |  Lab tech   |  05/12/2022 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your_data %>%
  mutate(`Start Date` = as.Date(`Start Date`, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  filter(`Start Date` - Sys.Date() >= 90)
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to also filter out people who exist in the remaining days of that month after their 90 days. Say they were hired on 02/03/22. I would actually need them to be filtered out until 06/01/22 even though their 90 days would be at 05/04/22.